# How to determine whether $addToSet inserted new value or not?

Tags: php, mongodb

`$addToSet` inserts new value into array if that value isn't already in that array and that's cool but the update method always returns the same response in both cases (when the value is already there and when it's not), which looks something like this:

```
Object {updatedExisting: true, n: 1, connectionId: 34, err: null, ok: 1}
```

Now I need to determine whether the last query actually inserted anything into the array or not. I use php driver.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not reported in the GLE response, there isn't any way to get this information outside of comparing/tracking the document state yourself. Below, I will explain why using the oplog is not a reliable solution.

If you're dealing with a replica set, the GLE response will include a `lastOp` field which tells you the timestamp and increment of the last oplog entry after the write was applied. Even for `$addToSet` operations that you'd think were a no-op, an oplog entry is created. If you were to use that to go look at the `local` database's `oplog.rs` collection, you'd find that the `$addToSet` is translated into a `$set` for the array field (the value being its state after `$addToSet` is executed). Even for "no-op" `$addToSet` operations, this will re-set the array's value, because the oplog needs a record to say "*this* field has *this* value as of *this* timestamp/increment."

Theoretically, you could backtrack through the oplog and look for the previous operation on the same document's array field to compare, but (1) you're not guaranteed that a previous operation is still in the oplog and (2) it's possible the array field was empty or missing before our operation.